# Set all current text from Edittext to upper case

Tags: android

Pretend that you wrote 5 lines of some text and you suddenly wanted it all to be in upper case! That is the problem I am trying to solve!

I have tried the `setInputFilter` method, but if that is chosen then I cannot use to lower case, even if I try to do that from the keyboard!

I have also tried the `Edittext.setAllCaps();` but that didn't do anything.
For info, it is a poem/quote-writing app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toUpperCase()`,

```
Edittext.setText(Edittext.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Dayum thanks it worked just like I wanted! great simple solution!